# if img < 500 apply css

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

i have this code:

```
var jq111 = jQuery.noConflict();

jq111('.slides img').each(function(){
    jq111self = jq111(this).height();
    if(jq111self < 500){
        jq111(this).addClass( "product-rescue" );
    }
});
```

if an image is less than 500 px apply a CSS class.

But there is a problem, is not working properly, and is applied 1/3 to images larger than 500px.

why?

https://jsfiddle.net/cuaqaxy8/3/

Comment: 100% sure you are checking the height before the image is loaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to wait for the image to load:

```
var jq111 = jQuery.noConflict();

jq111('.slides img').on("load", function() {
    var jq111self = jq111(this);
    if(jq111self.height() < 500){
        jq111self.addClass("product-rescue");
    }
});
```

Comment: any fiddle you could show? how about logging in the console the height right before using it to get some information?

Comment: @Halcyon the image loads once, so it dose not really matter.

Comment: FYI, the `.each()` method is redundant here: http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/py3o191z/1/ - looping will be handled and context passed within `.one()`.

Comment: Not sure it'll fix the problem, but the `jq111self ` variable should not be global.  `var jq111self = jq111(this);`

Comment: sorry , I was doing some tests. It does not work properly .

Comment: @EugenioSegala could you show a fiddle are an example? it works good by me

Comment: 1. that fiddle is not including jquery, here is one including jquery: https://jsfiddle.net/cuaqaxy8/2/ 2. anyway you could upload those images, so we could all see them? http://imgur.com/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89948/discussion-between-molow-and-eugenio-segala).